# Validating unique values in a domain entity

Tags: c#, design-patterns, domain-driven-design

I have a scenario where a domain entity property needs to be verified to be unique before it can be saved to the database. Here is a simple *Product* class. Let's assume I want to validate that when creating a new Product that the **ProductKey string property is unique**:

```
public class Product : EntityBase
{
    int ID { get; set; }
    string ProductKey { get; set; }
    int CategoryID { get; set; }

    bool IsValid
    {
        get
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ProductKey))
            {
                ValidationErrors.Add("ProductKey Required.");
            }

            if (CategoryID == 0)
            {
                ValidationErrors.Add("CategoryID Required.");
            }

            /* Validation that the product key is unique could go here? i.e. requires a database read. */

            return ValidationErrors.Count() == 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Since I'm using Domain Driven design the Product entity has no knowledge of persistence or the service layers. I could just add a check to the Service method as follows:

```
public class ProductService 
{
    private IProductRepository _productRepository = new ProductRepository();

    public int CreateProduct(Product item) 
    {
        if (item.IsValid)
        {
            if (ProductKeyIsUnique(item.ProductKey))
            {
                _productRepository.Add(item);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new DuplicateProductKeyException();
            }

        }
    }

    private bool ProductKeyIsUnique(string productKey)
    {
        return _productRepository.GetByKey(productKey) == null;
    }

}
```

This is simple enough but ideally I would like such logic to live in the domain model. Perhaps by raising some kind of validation event that can be caught by the service layer?

Is there a best practice or known design pattern for this type of scenario?

Comment: You should not have public setters for properties which are important or depends on other properties. If you do, the entity can at any time be set to an inconsistent state. Read here: http://blog.gauffin.org/2012/06/protect-your-data/

Comment: Sure, but this is just a simple example to convey my question. How would making the property setters private help me in this case? Do I then add data access concerns into my domain model?

Comment: I can't make the assumption that you do not do like that in DDD. All I see is an example which breaks encapsulation of the domain entity. But since it do not answer the question I just left a comment instead..

Comment: This is a simple example to convey my question - if I make the properties private as you suggest and move them to the constructor, then what? I've still set a value that needs to be unique at database level. Whether I set that value by a public setter or constructor is a trivial point.

Comment: @jgauffin I should add, I agree with your point re: encapsulation, but that's not what's being asked in this question.

Comment: That's why I said that I left a comment and not an answer... The answer you've already got is sufficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Product key uniqueness is not domain object knowledge. So you don't need domain validation for it. Why Product should care about key uniqueness? In my opinion it is an application layer responsibility. Your solution seems valid and right for me.

Comment: Agreed. Checking for uniqueness with a repository as well as possibly a database constraint is the general way this type of problem is resolve.

Comment: However, the format of the key may be domain specific. Such validation should be used within the domain entity when the key is set.

Comment: @jgauffin Yep, nice point. This is place where 'domain validation' comes into play.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution isn't safe for concurrent transactions, unless you use the serializable isolation level. I'd rather use a more simple solution. The common way to do this is to just use a unique constraint in the database. Trying to model this in your domain would only introduce unnecessary complexity.

Comment: I do have a constraint at the database level to act as the impenetrable barrier, I was just trying to catch this at a higher level and handle in a more elegant way than bubbling the exception up through layers. You raise an excellent point about concurrency!